# What is the precise meaning of '$n$ particles states' in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators

I am studying QFT and have some difficulties understanding the meaning of '$n$ particles states'.

First, I'm unsure whether the '$n$ particles' are distingushible or identical. I have understood that an '$n$ particles state' is simply a state of $n$ particles, and only the Lagrangian can determine which kinds of exist in the $n$ particle state. However, I can't be sure that my notion is right, so I want to ask a question and get further explanation about this.

Second, I have tried to solve Problem 6.3. of Schwartz, but I haven't been able to do it. The problem is to prove this identity, 6.22.

> It is probably worth saying a little more about what these operators $\mathcal{O}_n(x)$ are. The
> operators can be defined as they would be in quantum mechanics, by their matrix elements
> in a basis of states $ψ_n$ of the theory $C_{nm} = \langle ψ_n|\mathcal{O}|ψ_m\rangle$. Any such operator can be written
> as a sum over creation and annihilation operators:
> $$\mathcal{O}=\sum_{n,m}\int dq_1\cdots dq_ndp_1\cdots dp_m\,a^\dagger_{q_1}\cdots a^\dagger_{q_n}a_{p_1}\cdots a_{p_m}C_{nm}(q_1,\dots,p_m)\tag{6.22}$$

At first, I had tried to compute $\langle \psi_l|\mathcal{O}|\psi_j\rangle$ and prove that this is equal to $C_{lj}$. I had to prove the following

$$\sum_{n,m}\int dq_1\cdots dq_n\,dp_1\cdots dp_m\,\langle \psi_l|a^\dagger_{q_1}\cdots a^\dagger_{q_n}a_{p_1}\cdots a_{p_m}|\psi_j\rangle\,C_{nm}(q_1,\dots,p_m)=C_{lj}$$
so it had to be true that

$$\langle \psi_l|a^\dagger_{q_1}\cdots a^\dagger_{q_n}a_{p_1}\cdots a_{p_m}|\psi_j\rangle=\delta_{lj}$$

where $\delta_{lj}$ is the Kronecker delta.

However, according to my notion (please see the first question),

$$a_{p_m}\cdots a_{p_1}|\psi_j\rangle$$
means a ($j - m$) particles states $(j\geq m)$ because this state is equal to a state which we can get by annihilating $m$ particles from a $j$ particles states, but it can't yield the result above.
What shall I do?

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE. Do you require someone to specify whether the particles created are distinguishable or identical? Don't these words mean the same?

Comment: Yes, I do. I want someone to specify that. But it would be better if someone also explains a solution for Problem 6.3.